# lidR lasaddextrabytes does not update header

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

My `lidR` version is 2.0.2

I am trying to add an extrabyte about treeID that I get from raster (`lasmergespatial` with vector is super slow). I have a problem with saving that extrabyte to LAS file.

I have following code:

```
library(lidR)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

path <- "path/to/two/las_files.las"

setwd(path)
ctg <- catalog(path)

tif <- raster("Segmenty_Obszar13_TIF.tif")
las = readLAS(ctg$filename[[1]], filter = "-keep_class 4 5")
tif_crop = raster::crop(tif, raster::extent(las)*1.1)
las_tree = lasmergespatial(las, tif_crop, "treeID")
lasaddextrabytes(las_tree, name="treeID", desc="ID of a tree")
```

Now `las_tree` has summary:

```
class        : LAS (LASF v1.4)
point format : 7
memory       : 474.4 Mb 
extent       :7497590, 7498410, 5788790, 5789610 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref.  : NA 
area         : 670422.1 units² (convex hull)
points       : 4011573 points
density      : 5.98 points/units²
names        : X Y Z gpstime Intensity ReturnNumber NumberOfReturns ScanDirectionFlag EdgeOfFlightline Classification ScannerChannel Synthetic_flag Keypoint_flag Withheld_flag Overlap_flag ScanAngle UserData PointSourceID R G B Amplitude Pulse width treeID 
File signature:           LASF 
File source ID:           0 
Project ID - GUID:        00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
Version:                  1.4
System identifier:        LAStools (c) by rapidlasso GmbH 
Generating software:      lasheight (181108) commercial 
File creation d/y:        12/2019
header size:              375 
Offset to point data:     815 
Num. var. length record:  1 
Point data format:        7 
Point data record length: 40 
Num. of point records:    4011573 
Num. of points by return: 
Scale factor X Y Z:       0.01 0.01 0.01 
Offset X Y Z:             0 0 0 
min X Y Z:                7497590 5788790 -1.58 
max X Y Z:                7498410 5789610 38.92 
Variable length records: 
   Variable length record 1 of 1 
       Description:  RIEGL Extra Bytes 
       Extra Bytes Description:
          Amplitude: Echo signal amplitude [dB]
          Pulse width: Full width at half maximum [ns]
```

Seems like header is not updated after `lasaddextrabytes`. Am I doing something wrong?

I try also to write `las_tree` to new file:

```
writeLAS(las_tree, "new.las")
las_new = readLAS("new.las")
```

But `las_new` does not contain `"treeID"` attribute at all and the header is similar to the header of `las_tree`. How can I export LAS with extra bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I found the solution. I forgot that as from version 2.0 of `lidR`, point clouds are not passed by reference.

Here's the solution:

```
las_tree = lasaddextrabytes(las_tree, name="treeID", desc="ID of a tree")
```